# Concatenating JSX fragments with HTML and then rendering the accumulated result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to rewrite Board to use two loops to make the squares instead of hardcoding them. I've tried to concatenate these jsx fragments, I can't just append them like I would be able to if they were strings. Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance
This first snippet of code is what I've tried and it gives me a Object is an invalid React child error.

```js
class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={this.props.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i) } />;
  }

  render() {
    let board = null;
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i+=3)
    {
        let row = <div className="board-row">{this.renderSquare(i)}{this.renderSquare(i+1)}{this.renderSquare(i+2)}}</div>
        board = <div>{{board}}{{row}}</div>; 
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {board}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX transforms to `React.createElement(...)` function calls. These return objects, not strings, so you cannot concatenate them.

Just create an array of elements:

```
  render() {
    const rows = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i+=3)
    {
        rows.push(
          <div key={i} className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(i)}
            {this.renderSquare(i+1)}
            {this.renderSquare(i+2)}}
          </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {rows}
        </div>
    );
  }
```

[More about *lists* in React.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

---

> it gives me a Object is an invalid React child error.

In

```
 board = <div>{{board}}{{row}}</div>;
```

`{board}` is an object literal shorthand for `{board: board}`. Same for `{row}`. So this really is

```
board = <div>{{board: board}}{{row: row}}</div>;
```

As React tells you, it doesn't know how to render arbitrary objects.

*Maybe* you wanted

```
board = <div>{board}{row}</div>;
```

instead (`board` and `row` are React elements after all, so this works), but this would not produce the element structure you want.

Comment: Thank you Felix, I appreciate you breaking this down to me with explanations, and introducing the concepts I need to understand the underlying fundamentals. I can see that you used the key attribute in div, but it also works without the key attribute. Can you help me understand why that key attribute might be needed

Comment: @TonyKo: See the link. I think it explains it much better that I could. In a nutshell: react needs to know how to update exiting elements with new data. Using the loop index is usually not a good value use when you actually working with lists of data, but your use case is different.

Comment: alright cool. Appreciate all the help Felix and Sushanth! Thank you

Comment: for anyone else following this react tutorial, I found a very helpful example with all the extra steps completed by kelanwu: https://github.com/kelanwu/react-tic-tac-toe